# Does Cocona's school correspond to any real-life building?

Tags: tourism, flip-flappers

In several episodes, we see a shot of the main building of Cocona's school.

[image: school building]

Does this building correspond to anything that exists in real life? So far, my searches for `flip flappers real life` have only generated lists of [locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41gat.jpg) used in the Pure Illusion world of episode 7; I haven't found anything discussing the locations of the "real world" of the anime yet.

Comment: Based on a [google image search](https://www.google.com/imghp) it would seem to be a background based on the artist's imagination and experience.  To do an image search, open the image search page, and drag any image you want to the search bar.  Your image returned 5 pages of results, and from what I could read, all of them were general, "What beautiful backgrounds in *Flip Flappers*" type pages. But about 3 of those pages were non-English, so its possible one of them did specify a real-world location.